# an error appears every time i create an android project

Tags: java, android, r.java-file

every time i try to create an android project, lots of error appears at the console i searched for possible fixes but i don't know how to do it.

here is a line of the error

```
[2015-07-25 19:06:10 - r] E:\Workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:75: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'.
```

then the when i go to the mainactivity.java the R in R.layout.activity_main have the red jagged line under it. one of the way to fix it is to import 'R'(android). but if you do that the activity_main now have the red jagged line and the way to fix it is "Change to activity_list_item

please help me. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Put `your project` and `appcompat_v7` in the same folder and reset the references in project properties in Android category.

For example put them in:

```
E:\Workspace\appcompat_v7
```

and

```
E:\Workspace\your-project
```

Comment: @user3436362 In eclipse right click on project -> Properties -> Android -> Library -> Remove and then add the `appcompat_v7`